# Getting issue of Google Mobile Vision relying on deprecated UIWebview

Tags: ios, react-native, google-vision

Using this plugin on a project, I'm running into an Apple testflight warning that we're using UIWebView (ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage — Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs).

Searching for UIWebview references, it seems that the GoogleMobileVision pod is still referencing UIWebview, which may be triggering the error from Apple.

Running this command:- grep -r UIWebView ios/Pods/
getting:- Binary file ios/Pods//GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision matches

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: The only way is ask the git author update sdk. Not only you facing this problem at [HERE](https://github.com/googlesamples/ios-vision/issues/34)